# Conditional cross-validation sampling

Tags: cross-validation, survival

When applying cross-validation to evaluate the predictive performance of a binary classification model, **is it acceptable to separately sample from cases and non-cases to achieve class proportions in the training and testing partitions that closely match those in the original data set**?

My application is a Cox model (yes this is not a binary classifier). My data consist of ~500 non-cases and ~100 cases. When I partition the full data randomly for ten-fold cross-validation, there is high variance in the number of cases that make it to the test partition.

In the populations for which I'd like to make good predictions, however, the incidence of the disease I am studying is pretty similar to that in my data. I therefore feel as if my conventional cross-validation scheme provides estimates of the mean predictive performance over many parallel universes in which incidences vary hugely.

I have a feel that the answer should depend on the performance metrics used. What I use is net reclassification improvement, integrated discrimination improvement, and difference in C Index, to compare two models. All of these are sensitive to class proportions.

Should I sample separately? Should I not? And why?

Comment: I did the obvious thing and tried it. It does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Kohavi argues that stratified sampling to achieve near-equal class proportions in the CV folds is "best": Kohavi R. A Study of Cross-Validation and Bootstrap for Accuracy Estimation and Model Selection. In: Morgan Kaufmann; 1995:1137–1143.